# Is it possible to use paperjs in nodejs without using Cairo?

Tags: node.js, path, cairo, paperjs

I need to "read" an array of some paperjs paths in nodejs and get their dimension. I wanted to use paper npm module but saw that it has a dependency to **Cairo**.

As I'm deploying to heroku it is a little difficult to use Cairo. I know its possible but I want to know if its really necessary just for "reading" the dimensions of a path group.

Comment: You can use [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/), [CEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef) or [CEF python](https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/) to render images on a server.

Comment: I guess that Cairo is necessary for installation of node-canvas.
And it would be possible to install node-canvas on Heroku as [link](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation-on-Heroku).

Therefore, [1st. install paperjs without node-canvas, 2nd. install node-canvas on Heroku] might be possible to run paperjs on Heroku. (Sorry, I have not confirmed yet.)

Comment: Thanks for you replies, however I don't really need to draw on the server side - just calculated a few things using paper. Therefore I was hoping not to have to install Cairo. Do you think this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

A present day answer: 
**Yes it's possible**.

———

To quote [from the docs](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/develop/README.md#installing-paperjs-using-npm):

> Paper.js comes in three different versions on NPM: paper, paper-jsdom and paper-jsdom-canvas. Depending on your use case, you need to require a different one:
>
> - **paper** is the main library, and can be used directly in a browser context, e.g. a web browser or worker.
> - **paper-jsdom** is a shim module for Node.js, offering headless use with SVG importing and exporting through jsdom.
> - **paper-jsdom-canvas** is a shim module for Node.js, offering canvas rendering through Node-Canvas as well as SVG importing and exporting through jsdom.

**→ If you don't require rendering to canvas, paper-jsdom should do the trick** (which doesn't need Cairo)

———

**Important note:**
If I understood correctly this means you can't use PaperScript, but have to use JavaScript directly. 
This will affect how you have to write code:

- `new paper.Path()` instead of *new Path()*
- Create project manually using `paper.setup()`
- No mathematical operators (+ - * / %)
- ... ([More info in the docs](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/))

———

**A simple example to create a line, log its bounding box size (and also export the SVG):**

**Note:** I used this with the current Node LTS (v14.16.1)

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "paper-jsdom-example",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "paper-jsdom": "^0.12.15"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
const paper = require('paper');
const fs = require('fs');

var size = new paper.Size(300, 300)
paper.setup(size);

var path = new paper.Path();
path.strokeColor = '#348BF0';

var start = new paper.Point(100, 100);
var end = new paper.Point(200, 200);

path.moveTo(start);
path.lineTo(end);

console.log('width', path.bounds.width, 'height', path.bounds.height);

var svg = paper.project.exportSVG({asString:true});
fs.writeFileSync('punchline.svg', svg);
```